# Visual Studio Team Services Build Queue Not Appearing in List

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm setting up a build definition in Visual Studio Team Services using a Build Agent installed on my local machine for testing.

I'm following [these instructions](http://techtwaddle.net/2015/07/07/setting-up-an-on-premise-build-agent-with-visual-studio-online/) for creating a build agent, setting up a build definition, and queuing a build. I've created the agent on my local computer and it appears in the agent pool in VSTS. The agent is enabled and ready to go. I've also created a build definition that invokes my build script. Everything up to this point appears to work fine.

At this point I'm ready to queue a build and run it. The dialog for this looks like:

[image]

The dropdown labeled "Queue" only shows the `Hosted` agent pool. There should be a second pool called `Default` but it is not appearing. I can get it to "appear" by right clicking and inspecting the HTML and then using dev tools to change the value for the `Hosted` option. `Hosted`'s ID is `2`, I changed it to `1` since I assumed this to be the ID for `Default`. Once I do this I can click "OK" and the build runs as expected -- everything is checked out on my local machine by the build agent. Presumably my assumption about the ID value is correct.

So...everything it working correctly once I muck around with the plumbing a bit. But this is definitely not the way things *should* be working. Why is the `Default` queue not showing up in the dropdown? Do I need to flip a switch somewhere to make it work? Does my account not have enough access?

Some other details:

1. My account is a "Pool Administrator"
2. The build agent is **not** installed as a Windows service. I start it manually from a command prompt. I've not been able to install it as a service.
3. The machine that has the build agent installed on it is running Windows 10 x64 Pro. It was upgraded from Windows 8 x64 Pro.
4. I cannot use a hosted agent as I'm building a Unity project and Unity is not supported by for hosted agents.
5. I know I can use Unity Cloud Build but I do not want to.

### UPDATE

I've removed my previous Build Agent and installed a new one, as a service, on a Windows Azure VM running Windows 10 Enterprise x64. With this change the "Hosted" and "Default" queues are appearing as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Your account needs to also have access to the agent queue. Agent pools and agent queues are different entities, and being a "pool administration" does not necessarily mean you are a "queue administrator".

Comment: I am also a queue administrator. The problem seems to have resolved itself as "Default" and "Hosted" are appearing correctly now. The only thing that has changed is that my Build Agent is now installed as a service.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to execute the agent configuration in a console with elevated/administrator rights. If the agent configuration is done in a console with normal rights, the agent can still be configured properly, but its queue won't appear for selection when you will be queuing a new build.